# How to exclude $project computed field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have created a new field in the aggregation project to compare, and I don't want that field display in the final result. How can I exclude it?
Here is my example query. In this case, I want to hide the field `yearDate`. Is it possible?

```
db.user.aggregate([
    $project: {name: 1, yearDate: {$month: '$date'}, content: 1, date: 1}},
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    yearDate: {$ne: 2018}
                },
                {
                    content: /2018/
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            date: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Current Result

```
{ "date" : "2018-11-01 02:42:20", "content" : 'abc2018', "yearDate" : "2018", "name": "test"}
```

Expected Result

```
{ "date" : "2018-11-01 02:42:20", "content" : 'abc2018',"name": "test"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need additional [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#exclude-fields) stage to exclude that field from final result, try:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    $project: {name: 1, yearDate: {$month: '$date'}, content: 1, date: 1}},
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    yearDate: {$ne: 2018}
                },
                {
                    content: /2018/
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            date: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            yearDate: 0
        }
    }
]);
```